# React table check box deselect based on condtion

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have react table and it has checkbox in all row. Please refer to the sandbox URL
*https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-shape-9bm192*

My intention is to click one button to unselect 1st and 2nd row checkbox that is Id=1 & Id=2,the other row should remain same as per selection.

```
  const UsersTable = () => {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(initialData);
  const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, []);
  const data = useMemo(() => tableData, [tableData]);

  const handleValues = (processeddata) => {
    console.log(processeddata);
    // Here I want to handle some logic to make checkbox as unselect.
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} goUp={handleValues} />
    </>
  );
};

const Table = ({ columns, data, goUp }) => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    selectedFlatRows,
    state: { selectedRowIds },
    state,
    setGlobalFilter
  } = useTable({ columns, data }, useGlobalFilter, useRowSelect, (hooks) => {
    hooks.visibleColumns.push((col) => [
      {
        id: "selection",
        Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
          <TableCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
        ),
        Cell: ({ row }) => <Checkbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
      },
      ...col
    ]);
  });

  const enableSelectedUser = (event) => {
    goUp(selectedFlatRows);
    console.log(selectedFlatRows);
  };

  const { globalFilter } = state;

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={enableSelectedUser}>
        Click me! to unclick the checkbox
      </button>
      <TableContainer>
        <MUITable {...getTableProps()}>
          <TableHead>
            {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                  <TableCell {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                    {column.render("Header")}
                  </TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map((row) => {
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                <TableRow {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {row.cells.map((cell) =>
                    cell.column.id === "selection" ? (
                      <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                        {cell.render("Cell")}
                      </TableCell>
                    ) : (
                      <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                        {cell.render("Cell")}
                      </TableCell>
                    )
                  )}
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </MUITable>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

After selecting few checkbox in the list, If I click the button on top whatever checkbox I selected, in the selected list 1st and 2nd row checkbox should get unselected. I'm new to react please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react-table v7, according to [this](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowSelect#instance-properties) API docs, we can toggle selected row  by using **toggleRowSelected** function.

> **toggleRowSelected**: Function(rowPath: String, ?set: Bool) => void
>
> - Use this function to toggle a row's selected state.
> - Optionally pass true or false to set it to that state

This function is available at the table instance once we plug **useRowSelect** plugin at **useTable** hook.

```
const {
    ...
    toggleRowSelected
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data
    },
    useRowSelect,
    ...
  );
```

and to deselect the first two rows we can use:

```
const deselectFirstTwoRows = () => {
  const rowIds = [ 0, 1 ];
  rowIds.forEach(id => toggleRowSelected(id, false));
}
```

Here is the complete code.

[image: Edit eloquent-hypatia-wdjquw]